# Lua Save and Load with compression or some kind of encoding

Tags: lua, save, love2d

I want to make a save and a load system for my LÖVE or Love2d Game without any libraries. I want to save a single array with all the values, also in the load that if there is no file to load then automatically run `SaveGame()`.

```lua
function SaveGame()
   local data = {
      unpack(Controlls), -- 7 items
      unpack(PlayerSKin) -- 2 items
   }

   -- Saving the game in an unreadable by an 8y/o (If you know what i mean) way
end

function LoadGame()
   -- Loading the game
end
```

I tried compressing and things but they require string and I want to save an array and I don't know how to do it because it confusing for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a website where people write code for you so that you don't have to. If you need help debugging code that you have written, you must post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the specific problem with your code.

Comment: if `local data = {unpack(Controlls), unpack(PlayerSKin) }` is no pseudo code, then the resulting table will have 3 items (1+2) and not 9 items (7+2). The extra return values after the first one of the first `unpack()` call, will be discarded. Instead use a for loop and add them in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You are skipping a step. Serialize first, then compress.

Use any serializing library ([Json](https://github.com/rxi/json.lua), or more suitable [Lua serializer](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization)) and then slap the [compression from love.data](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.data.compress) onto it.

To load, repeat the steps in the opposite order.